# Hasse invariants of Wedderburn components of group rings attached to a group and a normal subgroup

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory, local-field, group-rings

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a normal subgroup. Let $F$ be a local field of characteristic zero. The group algebras $F[H]\subset F[G]$ are semisimple by Maschke’s theorem. Consider their Wedderburn decompositions. A Wedderburn component $M_{n_\chi}(D_\chi)$ of $F[G]$ corresponds to an irreducible characters $\chi$ of $G$, and similarly a Wedderburn component $M_{n_\eta}(D_\eta)$ of $F[H]$ corresponds to irreducible characters $\eta$ of $H$, where $D_\chi$ resp. $D_\eta$ are skew fields.

If $\eta$ is an irreducible constituent of the restriction $\chi_H$, is there a relationship between the Hasse invariants of $D_\chi$ and $D_\eta$?

Since the question involves a normal subgroup of a finite group, it sounds to me like the answer should involve Clifford theory, but I failed to find references for this.

Comment: If $F$ is a local field of characteristic zero then what's $F_p$?

Comment: That’s a typo, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (partial) answer to the question is given by Theorem 74.35 of Curtis–Reiner: Methods of Representation Theory, Volume 2, or equivalently by Proposition 3.8 of Yamada: The Schur Subgroup of the Brauer Group.

The statement there is true for any subgroup $H\le G$, that is, the normality assumption in the question if superfluous. The theorem gives a description in terms of $q$-parts of Brauer classes for all primes $q$ such that $q\nmid (\chi_H,\eta)$.